# HTTPS Protocol blocks JS

Tags: javascript, https, apache2, webserver, block

the HTTPS version of my website refuses to load JavaScript. All scripts are located on the same server.

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://server.tld/js/jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//server.tld/js/jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
```

But all browsers are blocking the content.

> "This page includes script from unauthenticated sources."

**EDIT**

It was my fault. I used some "http" links in the JavaScript file, so the browser didn't block the whole script but just because it uses some unencrypted urls.

Comment: Have you checked the server certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not getting a connect error for port 443 (the default for https) from the browser, it looks like it could be a certificate issue.

SSL requires the server to have an SSL certificate that allows connecting clients (i.e. browsers) to validate the identity of the server and encrypt data sent over that secure stream.  You need to obtain a certificate (if you don't already have one for that machine) from a certificate vendor like Thawte or Verisign, then make sure the web server is configured to use it.